# Current Row Delegated UITableView for hidden row

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a piece of code in which the UITableView is delegated. I want the use to edit feature for the rows in the table. When the user clicks on a row, the shouldChangeTextInRange is opened.

Via the following code I can control the editing of the row. This is working fine.

```
textView.text = ((ANFreeEditCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell].row inSection:0]]).getTekst;
```

It is also possible that one of the bottom rows in the table is edited. In which case the keyboard window is placed on top of the table and the `self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell].row` returns the zero row (0).

didSelectRowAtIndexPath is never called.

How can I access these rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the content offset of the table to make it programmatically scroll. Register for a `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and scroll the table so that the row being edited is not hidden behind the keyboard. I haven't tested it but i believe it should work

Hope this helps.

Considering Simon's suggestion

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didShowKeyBoard:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

-(void)didShowKeyBoard:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    float offset = //Value through which you need the tableview to scroll
    CGRect cellRect = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:_editCellIndexPath];
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, cellRect.origin.y - (offset-self.tableView.contentOffset.y));
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `observer` of `keyboard notification` inside your method lets say `viewDidLoad` inside that include this two `NSNotification` which will call when `keyboard` will hide and show:-

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
     selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
     name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification    
     object:self.view.window];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
     selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
     object:self.view.window];
```

Now after that implement the two method of keyboard hide and show accordingly and then just set the frame of your `tableview` depends on your view size. For eg.

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  //return it to its original position
  [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(3, 403, 695, 353)]; 
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  //Or where ever you want the tableView to go
  [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(3, 65, 695, 353)]; 
}
```

Comment: You don't need to leave comments all over the place telling people to look at your answer. It's not very classy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this does not answer my question, it is not related to the question. The question is how to know which row is being edited.